# Flutter: How to display data from the snapshot outside?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not able to read the data outside from the snapshot. How can I reveal the data `docname` and `docage` outside of `snapshot.data!.docs.map((document)`? I will also need to route these data to another as well.

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email)
            .collection('Passenger List').snapshots(),
    
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if(!snapshot.hasData){ return const Center( child: Text("Loading..."),);}
       else {
        int snapdata = snapshot.data!.size;
        int total = price * int.parse(snapdata.toString());
        // <= Place docname and docage here, but how?
          return Column(
             children: [
              Table(
                border: TableBorder.all(),
                children: [
                  //Passenger()
                  TableRow(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        //Row 1 - Number of Passengers
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                           child: Text("Number of Passengers: ${snapdata ?? '0'}", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20,))),
                           ListView(
                            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                              String docname = document['Name'];
                              int docage = document['Age'];
                              print("Name: $docname   Age: $docage");
                               return Container(
                                width: 20,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                 child: Card(
                                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255,245,184,184),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                    child: ListTile(title: Text("Name: $docname   Age: $docage"),
                                    ))),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                         ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    //Bottom Here
                    Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB( 0, 45, 0, 0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return const Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator(), )} 
                              else {
                                return Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(flex: 2,
                                      child: Container(
                                        color: const Color.fromARGB(255,209,211,211),
                                        height: 80,
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                          children: [Text("Total Price: RM $total") //${price * 2}
                                                     ]),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(flex: 1,
                                                  child: SizedBox(
                                                    height: 80,
                                                    child:ElevatedButton(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255,137,242,228),),
                                                    onPressed: () {if (total <= 0) {} 

                                                     else { Navigator.push(context,
                                                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
                                                     QRGen(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email, _searchString, _searchString2, 
                                                     _searchdate, duration, price, total, snapdata//, docname, docage
                                                     ))); //
                                                     }
                                                    },
                                                     child: const Text("Continue")),
                                                     ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ));
                                              }
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        )),
                                  ],
                                );
                                }
                              }),
                        ),
```

Comment: Can anyone lend me a help?

Comment: Can you please show your database for more clarity

Comment: Here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdL0r.png